# Is stackoverflow a comfort for copy paste code?

Tags: discussion

Does spending too much of time in StackOverflow decreases the research time? If someone doesn't know something like a code he asks it and gets response and copy pastes it to use the code and marks it as an answer. Does people who really ask for code samples really understand the code or the copy paste comfort spoiling the programmer research time?

Comment: Ultimately if people are using stack exchange answers wrong (by just copy pasting rather than understanding them) then thats their look out

Comment: @BilltheLizard I don't get you

Comment: @treak he's saying when people use the answers the wrong way, that's their problem.

Comment: If this question was presented in a certain way, it would be a very compelling issue to discuss.  There *is* a shady region  ,a shady seesaw of sorts, between teaching users to ride the bike and giving them a  piggyback ride on the motorcycle. BUT I DIGRESS ;-)

Comment: This is a matter of opinion

Answer (score 18):

> Does spending too much of time in StackOverflow decreases the research time?

Stack Overflow is *supposed* to decrease your research time.

> If someone doesn't know something like a code he asks it and gets response and copy pastes it to use the code and marks it as an answer.

Questions just asking for code without showing any prior effort at all are supposed to be closed. There's a close template specifically for them.

> Does people who really ask for code samples really understand the code or the copy paste comfort spoiling the programmer research time?

No, people who simply ask for code probably often don't understand samples that they copy/paste off the internet.  We can stop them from asking here, but we can't stop them from copy/pasting code they don't understand from other people's questions and answers. It's up to each individual to do their research, study their craft, and try to understand the solutions to their problems.  I don't know if Stack Overflow itself can do any more to guide people in the right direction.

Comment: I came across the post of how much research time you need to post a question. Doesn't SO need to be last resort after a lot of research time? @Bill The Lizard

Comment: @xtreak It doesn't need to be the *last* resort, but asking a new question on Stack Overflow shouldn't be the first thing you do either.  Googling, browsing language-specific tutorials, and searching Stack Overflow for existing answers should come first.

Comment: I guess Jon Skeet reduces a lot of research time @Bill The Lizard

Answer (score 3):

Let me be a newbie-friendly for you! :)

> Does spending too much of time in StackOverflow decreases the research time?

Stackoverflow is generally meant to shorten the hit and trial method time not the research time. On the about page, Stackoverflow's team has mentioned that you must search thoroughly for the results first and then come back to have the answer for that question. But you have to **search for that question** on Internet.

> If someone doesn't know something like a code he asks it and gets response and copy pastes it to use the code and marks it as an answer.

Well, here come two points.

1. If he has the research, lets say nice written question and good explainations of what he did, what he wanted and what went wrong. He must show what he searched for to satisfy the terms where it is stated that user must search for the solution. Then, if he gets a solution to his code he can use it by copy pasting or by just updating the code of his. Its his will!
2. If he has no research, lets say if he just knows that there is something known as jQuery and he can use this to hide/show the elements but doesn't know how to write the code for that and he asks that on Stackoverflow, he will get closed as duplicate and the first question or the best question will be linked there. Or some users will comment on his question and will provide him with the link to the jQuery API.

> Does people who really ask for code samples really understand the code or the copy paste comfort spoiling the programmer research time?

A developer will never keep asking for code sample. Only a beginner will ask for it. If you're a beginner then don't feel pity or shy to ask for samples, many communities will provide you with a sample. You can never understand a well written code that a developer; who wrote it, can understand. You need to ask for sample or explaination. However, using a ready-made code might help the programmer sometimes. For example for a game developer it will be hard to write the code to handle the Hardware events such as mouse and keyboard as compared to using DirectX which was developed by Microsoft. So you can't just blame them! :)

So for me, if someone needs a code sample or a snippet of my code, I don't feel angry to provide him with one, as he needs to learn. And I don't want anyone to go through the same situations that I had to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Its not about copy pasting the code,StackOverflow is here to help us. But if the user simply copy pastes the answer that he has received, then he will be the one at loss because, i guess no one here provides you the exact answer for the question asked.

Its just a generalised answer.
Thanks.

Comment: On the contrary - lots of people provide exact, verbatim answers, and lots of others will copy those answers verbatim into their assignments, or production code.

Comment: In that case, I feel then we must all decide that, atleast from now on,we provide answers that will let the person asking the question THINK on how to go about it rather than giving complete precise answers.

Answer (score -3):

It just depends on how you use the platform, preferably you use Stack Overflow when you have tried your best to find a solution.